# A simple yet hard task for (theoretically) Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

*Sorry if I don't use the words properly, I haven't learnt these things in English, only some of the words.
Anyway, I'm practicing to one of my exams and sadly this task seemed more challanging for me than it should be. Some kind of explain would help a lot!*

10 meters of clothes have 6 holes in it.

a) What kind of distribution does the number of holes per meter follow? (*I think it must be Poisson distribution)*

b) What's the probability that there's more than 10 holes in 5 meters of clothes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Poisson model is not unreasonable. So if $X$ is the number of holes in a $1$ meter piece of cloth, then it is reasonable to assume that $X$ has a more or less Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda =\dfrac{6}{10}$.

Let $Y$ be the number of holes in a random $5$ meters of cloth. Then it is reasonable to assume that $Y$ has more or less Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda=6\cdot\frac{5}{10}=3$.

The probability there are more than $10$ holes is $1$ minus the probability there are $10$ or fewer holes. The probability there are $10$ or fewer holes is 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{10} e^{-3}\frac{3^i}{i!}.$$

The calculation is a little unpleasant. The last few terms are pretty small, and are not really terribly relevant. One should realize that the Poisson model is only a model. It fits reality modestly well, but one should not expect a  high accuracy fit.

Comment: But I can't get, why λ = 6/10? Because I know that I was wrong with it, while I tried to calculate. I thought that λ = 10.

Comment: If the random variable $W$ is the number of holes in a $10$ meter stretch, then $w$ has parameter $6$. For a $k$ meter stretch, the parameter becomes $(6)\frac{k}{10}$. The parameter is always the **mean** number of holes in the length described. The mean number of holes per one meter stretch is $\frac{6}{10}$.

Comment: So the mean number a.k.a the expected value a.k.a λ equals k (the number of events cause) divided by the given period of time/surface ? Thank you very much. I didn't know that because I totally missed it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You are right , it's the Poisson distribution. Think like : ***6 trains come every 10 hours***

Therefore, in $5$ hours the expected number of trains is $3$. Thus, the $\lambda$ in our distribution is $3$.

Back to the problem, the probability that $k$ holes appear in $5$ meters of cloth is $$P(X=k)=\dfrac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}=\dfrac{3^ke^{-3}}{k!}$$ 
Thus, we need the probability: $$P(X>10)=1-P(X\leq10)=$$
$$1-[P(0)+P(1)+\dots+P(9)+P(10)]$$
Now, it is a matter of calculations.

Comment: @André Nicolas mentioned above that λ = 6/10. Well that's what I couldn't get. The formula and the 1-P(X<=10) was okay for me. Thank you anyway!

Comment: $\lambda$ is the expected number of events in a given period of time. Andre Nicolas says that if our "time interval" is $1$, then the parameter is $6/10$. If we change our interval to $5$ meters, then the parameter changes to $\lambda =3$

Comment: I can believe it, but why it isn't wrong? Since Poisson is not a symmetrical distribution, so it may happens that I can find more holes on 5 meters then 3. Sounds too easy.

Comment: Well, there is a probability that you find $100$ holes in $3$ meters! $5$ is just the expected number of holes.

Comment: Just like 6 about 10 meters - and because this is just the expected value, the number of holes and the length are proportional, isn't it?